How to extract non-sensitive secrets from a Terraform file and set them as environment variables?
I am working with a Terraform file that declares secrets as either sensitive or non-sensitive. My objective is to extract only the non-sensitive secrets and set them as environment variables for better accessibility. I plan to use the output variables defined in an output file, but I am unsure how to proceed. Is there an automated way to do this?
Here is an example of my Terraform code:
variable "tag" {
type=string
description="EC2 Instance Type"
sensitive=false
}

variable "user_name"{
type=string
sensitive=true
}


You want to do that from the variables or from outputs?

Variables will do. I thought it would be easier to do from the outputs !

So for example you would want to export the tag variable value, but not user_name? Outputs are probably a better way to go anyway.

Yes, basically I need to extract the secrets where sensitive=false.

Not sure how helpful this will be for your specific scenario, but you can use a combination of terraform commands with jq to get the non-sensitive output values.
Example
Consider the following code:
output "sensitive1" {
  value = "sensitive1"
  sensitive = true
}

output "sensitive2" {
  value = "sensitive2"
  sensitive = true
}

output "non_sensitive1" {
  value = "non_sensitive1"
  sensitive = false
}

output "non_sensitive2" {
  value = "non_sensitive2"
  sensitive = false
}

Running terraform plan -out=tfplan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + non_sensitive1 = "non_sensitive1"
  + non_sensitive2 = "non_sensitive2"
  + sensitive1     = (sensitive value)
  + sensitive2     = (sensitive value)

Running terraform show -json tfplan | jq '.planned_values.outputs' to show the output values:
{
  "non_sensitive1": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "non_sensitive1"
  },
  "non_sensitive2": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "non_sensitive2"
  },
  "sensitive1": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "sensitive1"
  },
  "sensitive2": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "sensitive2"
  }
}

Running terraform show -json tfplan | jq '.planned_values.outputs | with_entries(select(.value.sensitive == false))' to get only the non-sensitive outputs:
{
  "non_sensitive1": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "non_sensitive1"
  },
  "non_sensitive2": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "non_sensitive2"
  }
}

PS: I've used Terraform v1.9.1-dev to run the above commands.

The answer provided by @Rui Jarimba is the most comprehensive and universal so it would be the go-to solution in most cases.
But if you would like to check if a variable is set as sensitive you can use the issensitive function (introduced in Terraform 1.8).
For example, you can use it to be sure that a resource will be created only when a variable is non-sensitive:
resource "terraform_data" "environment_variables" {
  count = !issensitive(var.tag) ? 1 : 0
  
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "<COMMAND> $VAR1"

    environment = {
      VAR1 = var.tag
    }
  }
}

In the above example, I used local-exec provisioner to show that you can invoke any command/script from inside Terraform code. More about provisioners - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax
